# Qual a função de rotas filhas no angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, component, router

A função de rota filha no angular serve somente para renderizar o componente da rota filha no componente da rota pai? Pois eu queria fazer justamente o inverso. Eu gostaria de quando eu for da rota pai para a rota filha, eu gostaria de renderizar na tela somente o template da rota filha. Existe como fazer isso?

```
{ 
   path: 'my-curriculum', component: MyCurriculumComponent, 
   children: [
      { path: 'general-information', component: CurriculumFormComponent },
      { path: 'job', component: CurriculumFormComponent },
      { path: 'education', component: CurriculumFormComponent },
      { path: 'extracurricular-activity', component: CurriculumFormComponent }
  ]
}
```

Comment: O template de `my-curriculum` é diferente das rotas filhas? Se for, voce pode fazer um loadChildren e dentro do modulo de rotas desse componente voce o template exclusivo para as rotas filhas

Comment: Ou voce pode fazer o `MyCurriculumComponent` ser o template principal de dentro da rota filha `{path: '', component: SeuComponent}`ser a rota principal que usaria o template do MyCurriculumComponent

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi sua pergunta, basta adicionar o componente router-outlet no componente que tem as rotas filhas, as rotas children servem pra serem renderizadas dentro do componente pai, assim criando uma navegação interna no componente